# Effect chaining - CSS Equivalent for effect.setInput in javafx

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I need to apply multiple effects ( mainly innershadow and dropshadow ) through CSS. But I'm not able to chain these effects.
 Is there CSS equivalent for [setInput()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/Shadow.html#setInput(javafx.scene.effect.Effect)) of javafx.scene.effect.Effect?
So far I found only [this](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29343) link. It indicates something about fixes but no details about how to use chaining.
**EDIT**: Further explanation if question is not clear:
to apply effect through css, `-fx-effect` is used. I need to apply multiple effects to same node. How to "chain" these effects in CSS? This can be easily done through code using setInput() mentioned earlier.
TIA

Comment: Do you mean in such a manner as: box-shadow: inset 0 2px 6px #000, 0 2px 6px #000;

Comment: Edited question for further explanation

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible in Java 7 nor in Java 8 to chain effects or apply multiple effects via CSS. See the [Oracle CSS Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect).

It's also mentioned in the [CSS vs Code](http://www.canoo.com/blog/2012/07/10/javafx-recipes-css-vs-code/?lang=de) article.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lorand mentions, it's not possible to chain effects via CSS.

He also gives the link of a well known example of chaining effects via code.

I'll provide a solution with FXML, using that same example to compare results.

By (updated) code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException { 
    Circle circle = new Circle(64,64,48);
    Paint fill = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
                                new Stop(0.0, Color.rgb(207, 0, 58)),
                                new Stop(1.0, Color.rgb(129, 0, 33)));
    circle.setFill(fill);
    circle.setStroke(null);
    InnerShadow innerShadow = new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN,Color.color(0, 0, 0, 0.65),5,0,0,-5);
    InnerShadow innerGlow = new InnerShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN,Color.color(1, 1, 1, 0.65),5,0,0,5);
    innerGlow.setInput(innerShadow);

    DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow(BlurType.GAUSSIAN, Color.color(0, 0, 0, 0.65), 5, 0, 0, 0);
    dropShadow.setInput(innerGlow);

    circle.setEffect(dropShadow);

    VBox vBox = new VBox(circle);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,200,200,Color.web("#a9a9a9"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Chain effect by code");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that the effects are defined in reverse order of application. For the sake of clarity, we could also write this:

```
circle.setEffect(dropShadow);
dropShadow
    .setInput(innerGlow);
    innerGlow
        .setInput(innerShadow);
```

Now let's use Scene Builder 2.0 to create an FXML file `circle.fxml`.

Once we have the circle, we set the `DropShadow` effect, and then we edit the effect, and select `Replace Effect Input` option from the menu button:

[image: Applying chain effect 1]

Then choose `InnerShadow`, define the effect, and select again `Replace Effect Input`, selecting again `InnerShadow`:

[image: Applying chain effect 2]

Define the effect, save and exit. This will be the source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Circle radius="48.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="1.0">
         <fill>
            <LinearGradient endX="0.0" endY="1" proportional="true" startX="0" startY="0">
               <stops>
                  <Stop color="#cf003a" offset="0.0" />
                  <Stop color="#810021" offset="1.0" />
               </stops>
            </LinearGradient>
         </fill>
         <effect>
             <DropShadow blurType="GAUSSIAN" color="#000000a6" radius="5.0">
               <input>
                  <InnerShadow blurType="GAUSSIAN" color="#ffffffa6" offsetY="5.0" radius="5.0">
                     <input>
                        <InnerShadow blurType="GAUSSIAN" color="#000000a6" offsetY="-5.0" radius="5.0" />
                     </input>
                  </InnerShadow>
               </input>
            </DropShadow>
         </effect>
      </Circle>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Finally, loading this file in our scene:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException { 
    VBox vBox = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("circle.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox,200,200,Color.web("#a9a9a9"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Chain effect by FXML");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This will be the result:

[image: Chain of Effects]