# JavaFX - Getting class cast exception in css for blend mode

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

[JavaFX CSS Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) suggests to set blend mode through CSS as follows:

```
-fx-blend-mode: blue
```

But on applying following CSS string to a Text node I'm getting an exception:

```
-fx-blend-mode:green;
-fx-fill:rgba(0.501960813999176,0.4000000059604645,0.800000011920929,1.0);
-fx-font-size:52;
-fx-font-style:normal;
-fx-font-weight:normal
```

Exception:

```
Dec 05, 2014 12:54:23 PM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.paint.Color cannot be
     cast to java.lang.String' while converting value for '-fx-blend-mode' from
     inline style on Text[text="Title At Company", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT,
     origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System,
     style=Regular, size=13.0], fontSmoothingType=GRAY, fill=0x000000ff]
```

Is the CSS string wrong or what?
I need to apply blend mode through CSS only.

Comment: How to apply css ? Can you show code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try setting the property `-fx-blend-mode` with other possible values, most of them will work. But these don't: `add`, `blue`, `green` and `red`.

With some debugging you can find this method `CSSParser.parse()` that's been called to parse the rule `-fx-blend-mode:green;`:

```
if (needsLookup || ((value = colorValueOfString(str)) == null )) {
    value = new ParsedValueImpl<String,String>(str, null, isIdent || needsLookup);
}
```

You can see that if the string ("green", "red", "blue") matches a color, then it will be parsed as `Color`. And then the rule will fail, complaining because it was expecting a `BlendMode` enum, parsed from the string, not from a color.

Note this happens to `add` too, since it's converted to 0xaaddddff.

The workaround here is setting it by code:

```
text.setBlendMode(BlendMode.GREEN);
```

Finally, these values won't work: `src-in` and `src-out`, since they were removed from `BlendMode`. You can't set them by code, but you still can select them via CSS. You will get this warning:

```
Caught java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode.src_in' ...
```

Consider filing a bug to Jira if you think this should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It seems JavaFX CSS has a lot of bugs and is not a complete alternative to using styling nodes through code. Can you suggest solution to my another problem with CSS? effect chaining (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293885/effect-chaining-css-equivalent-for-effect-setinput-in-javafx/27310236#27310236)

Comment: You can chain effects, by code or with FXML. But not by CSS. Do you want an answer with any of these options?

Comment: @Rutaraj JavaFX CSS is not supposed to be a complete alternative to styling nodes through code (though it is pretty flexible and you can do a lot of styling in CSS alone).  Yes, JavaFX CSS processing does have some bugs, but (in my experience with recent JavaFX versions), these are encountered quite rarely.  Definitely, you should [file a bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) regarding the issue you found - issues in the bug tracker have a greater chance of getting resolved than issues noted on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JoséPereda suggest an anwer with FXML. If possible also suggest a way to store effects in DB/JSON string for reproducing exact effects without using CSS string.

Comment: @RuturajPatil I've answer your question related chain effects with code and FXML. Following the order of application it easy to store and replicate. By the way, did you see my answer to your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171885/display-custom-color-dialog-directly-javafx-colorpicker)? Any comments?